# Unable to create a new entry in Apache Directory studio for LDAP integration with AEM

Tags: ldap, aem

Getting following error:

> Error while creating entry
>    - [LDAP: error code 67 - NOT_ALLOWED_ON_RDN: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUES
>     java.lang.Exception: [LDAP: error code 67 - NOT_ALLOWED_ON_RDN: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
>   Message ID : 15
>       Add Request :
>   Entry
>       dn[n]: cn=bella+uid=bella+userPassword=54321,dc=example,dc=com
>       objectClass: person
>       objectClass: top
>       objectClass: uidObject
>       uid: bella
>       sn: mcdonald
>       cn: bella
>       userPassword: 0x35 0x34 0x33 0x32 0x31 
>   : ERR_62 Entry cn=bella+uid=bella+userPassword=54321,dc=example,dc=com does not have the userPassword attributeType, which is part of the RDN";]
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1374)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$9(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1342)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$6.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:958)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1269)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1205)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.createEntry(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:980)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.createEntry(CreateEntryRunnable.java:225)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.run(CreateEntryRunnable.java:124)
>       at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>
> [LDAP: error code 67 - NOT_ALLOWED_ON_RDN: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
>   Message ID : 15
>       Add Request :
>   Entry
>       dn[n]: cn=bella+uid=bella+userPassword=54321,dc=example,dc=com
>       objectClass: person
>       objectClass: top
>       objectClass: uidObject
>       uid: bella
>       sn: mcdonald
>       cn: bella
>       userPassword: 0x35 0x34 0x33 0x32 0x31 
>   : ERR_62 Entry cn=bella+uid=bella+userPassword=54321,dc=example,dc=com does not have the userPassword attributeType, which is part of the RDN";]

I have tried on 6.1 and 6.3 version of AEM, but it is still not working.

Comment: If you’re using apache directory studio, whats it have to do with AEM? What exact steps are you doing to reproduce this?

Answer (score 3):

The error message says:

Your client is trying to add an entry with RDN `cn=bella+uid=bella+userPassword=54321` but the entry itself does not contain the attribute with the value `userPassword: 54321`.

Whatever LDAP client you're using this is a horrible security nightmare!

You really MUST NOT put the *userPassword* in the RDN because it would be readable for any LDAP client allowed to search the user entry.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here :

Grabbed this from your error message : `cn=bella+uid=bella+userPassword=54321,dc=example,dc=com`

Issue #1 : Fundamentally, you are doing wrong. Please do not put `userPassword` in your DN ever. Everyone can see that password. DNs are not hidden.

Issue #2 : The objectClass included in the LDAPEntry do not contain the attribute `userPassword`. Please include `organizationalPerson` or `user` in your LDAP entry.